# Can I display only columns of a Table of a Particular Data Type in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sqldatatypes

I am going through database tables with several columns. I was trying to view columns with a smalldatetime data type side by side for comparison.

So is there a way/ a query in which I can access the columns of a table that have the same datatype displayed together ?

Am working on SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here. Are you wanting to only select columns from a table that have a certain datatype? You can query sys.columns to determine the datatype.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  
    t.name,  
    o.name AS TableName,  
    c.*  
FROM  
    sys.columns c  
JOIN  
    sys.types t ON t.user_type_id = c.user_type_id  
JOIN  
    sys.objects o ON o.object_id = c.object_id  
WHERE  
    t.name='smalldatetime'
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

You cannot use this directly, but you can build dynamic SQL from there:

```
DECLARE @sch VARCHAR(100)='dbo'; --or other schema
DECLARE @tbl VARCHAR(100)='YourTableName';
DECLARE @tp VARCHAR(100)='INT'  --or other type

DECLARE @cols VARCHAR(MAX)=
(
    STUFF(
        (
        SELECT ',' + COLUMN_NAME 
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
        WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA=@sch 
          AND TABLE_NAME=@tbl 
          AND DATA_TYPE=@tp
        FOR XML PATH('')
        ),1,1,''
     )
);
DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(MAX)=
'SELECT ' + @cols + ' FROM ' + @sch + '.' + @tbl;

EXEC(@cmd);
```